# ios push notification retrieve message for later display

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way for me to load the messages that has been sent to the device and display it again in my app? if so, can someone point me in the right direction.  I want to create a view in my app that would display all the notification sent to the device for that app.